# Aggregating row labels

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

The code below lists account numbers by the shop code they belong to and puts a label next to the account such as 'Expired', 'Active' or 'Old'. I would like to be able to create a summary by each shop code which shows how many of each account type they have for example shop_thames = 1 old, 4 active and 10 expired. How would I achieve this?

```
SELECT
shop_code,
CASE WHEN MAX(i_date) < DATEADD(day , - 180 , GETDATE()) THEN 'Expired' WHEN MAX(i_date) > DATEADD(day , - 30 , GETDATE())THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Old' END AS Account_Type,
account_id,
SUM(Revenue) AS Spend

FROM 
[company].[dbo].name

WHERE
Date_Reporting_LY = '2016'
AND  Total_Revenue > 0

GROUP BY
shop_code,
account_id
```

Comment: sql-server-2012

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
select  shop_code, account_type, count(*)
  from (SELECT  shop_code,
               CASE WHEN MAX(i_date) < DATEADD(day , - 180 , GETDATE()) THEN 'Expired' WHEN MAX(i_date) > DATEADD(day , - 30 , GETDATE())THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Old' END AS Account_Type
          FROM  [company].[dbo].name    
         WHERE Date_Reporting_LY = '2016'
           AND  Total_Revenue > 0 ) x   
GROUP BY  shop_code, Account_Type
```

Comment: I have tried this and it just gives me 1 values in my results column. I then tried doing some SUM(CASE Statements in the outer select to see if this would work but I only get a 0 or a 1. I think this is because it is looking against the shop code rather than adding up the values by account_id.

Comment: Because it won't aggregate a total of each account type by shop code.

Comment: You originally asked for "a summary by each shop code which shows how many of each account type they have" Which I would assume you meant a count of each account type within each shop_code. Do you want the totals by account types as columns? Can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your query mostly as is, and wrap it in another select:

```
SELECT shop_code, account_type, count(*)
FROM (
SELECT
shop_code,
CASE WHEN MAX(i_date) < DATEADD(day , - 180 , GETDATE()) THEN 'Expired' WHEN MAX(i_date) > DATEADD(day , - 30 , GETDATE())THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Old' END AS Account_Type,
account_id,
SUM(Revenue) AS Spend

FROM 
[company].[dbo].name

WHERE
Date_Reporting_LY = '2016'
AND  Total_Revenue > 0

GROUP BY
shop_code,
CASE WHEN MAX(i_date) < DATEADD(day , - 180 , GETDATE()) THEN 'Expired' WHEN MAX(i_date) > DATEADD(day , - 30 , GETDATE())THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Old' END
account_id
) x
GROUP BY 
shop_code,
account_type
```

One change to your original query - MySQL doesn't insist that you group by all elements in a select outside of aggregate functions, but it is really best practice to do so. If you group by the entire case statement, as shown, you avoid issues in aggregating by values you can't see.